# How to add search bar under navigation bar and create a actionsheet by clicking on search bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.2

In my app I want to put searchbar under the navigationbar and also want to display actionsheet which includes the tableview in it.

How is it possible to create actionsheet by clicking on the search bar and items should be search from the tableView?

Here is the screenshot about what I exactly want.

[image: In this image by clicking on searchbar actionsheet will open and search is perform on the tableview in the actionsheet.]

Please suggest me the way tho do this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your app just targeting iPad?

Comment: yup this app is for ipad and it also includes splitview functionality and in detailviewController of splitview i have to add this search functionality

Comment: Ok then my answer suits your requirement as my answer also applies for the iPad. I think Ray Wenderlich's link in my answer does half your job done.

Comment: I think I have edited my answer after I saw your screenshot in your question. Check my answer now. I have edited my answer and that would surely give you an idea what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to implement Search Bar as you do normally i.e. to filter array data based on search bar input from the user.

Then on `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` or `searchBarTextDidEndEditing:`, you need to present the UIPopOverViewController with a tableView inside it as shown in Ray Wenderlich's tutorial (I have posted its link below) and show the results in there by passing the data array on that tableView.

Here is information about the [UISearchBarDelegate Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

For UIPopOverController refer to this link below:

[UIPopOverController Tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)

Hope this helps